# How to compute Common Eigenvector of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

what the definition of common eigenvector? Could you give me an example 2 matrices that have common egienvector. Thanks

Comment: If two matrices commute, they have at least one common eigenvector.

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy: take any eigenvector $v$ of a matrix $A$. It is also an eigenvector of the identity matrix. Of course the eigenvalues are different.